# Why is my Post method not working?

Tags: php, post

Sorry in advance if this is a really stupid mistake, but I appreciate any help that can be given.

This is the code that initialise that data in the form. They are radio buttons that are populated via an SQL database.

```
 echo "<form method='post' action='home.php'>";
$result = queryMySQL("SELECT Name FROM Quotees");
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    $error = "<span class='error'>No people can be found</span><br><br>";
} else {
    $numrow = $result->num_rows;
    for ($count = 1; $count <= $numrow; $count++) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $name = stripslashes($row['Name']);
        echo '<input type="radio" name="choice" value="' . $name . '"  />' . $name;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Later on in the code I try to access the value picked using the POST method, as follows:

```
$personPicked = stripslashes($_POST["choice"]);
if ($person === $personPicked) {
    //code
} else {
    echo "wrong answer";
}
```

The error I receive is "Undefined index: choice" on the line where the POST method is called.

I submit the form using the following code out side of the php segment as HTML code

```
<div class="confirmButton">
<form action="home.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Thanks for any help you can give as to why my code isn't working/how I can go about solving the problem.

Comment: **Danger** — `stripslashes` is not suitable for protecting data that is to be inserted into HTML! Use `htmlspecialchars`!

Comment: Can you var_dump() $_POST array? How do you submit the form?

Comment: You need to debug the data to track down the source of the problem. Look at the POST request in the developer tools in your browser. Is the data there? Look at the HTML that you are generating. Is it correct? Are the values there? Have you checked that a radio button is actually checked?

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @BenRoob when i do var_dump it originally returns null. Once i press submit it changes value to the value of the radio button that was picked when submit was pressed. I understand why this is so thankyou.

Do you know how to go about making sure that the value changes before the submit button is pressed?

Comment: my answer was wrong... Quentin's answer should be accepted. Didn't get it at first sight, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The submit button is in a **different** form.

When you click it, you submit the form that *does not include the radio buttons*.

You need to put the submit button and the radio buttons in **the same form**.

Comment: I have done this - I did have it like this originally but everything got a bit messed up during debugging.

Comment: Okay this doesn't seem to make a difference overall because my problem is not what i thought it was, thankyou anyway